# Php Carbon, get the php date format mask from a date string

Tags: php, php-carbon

Using `php` `Carbon` I can format a date like this:

```
$strDate = $dt->format('l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A')->toDateTimeString();
```

to get

```
Thursday 25th of December 1975 02:15:16 PM
```

Is it possible to query the date string and get back the `php` format string?

Like this:

```
echo getPhpFormatFromDateString($strDate);
```

to get this:

```
l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A
```

Comment: By looking at [Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)?

Comment: just cast the format to a variable. $format = 'l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A'; then do $strDate = $dt->format($format)->toDateTimeString();

Comment: @Parker Dell thanks for the reply. I am looking to get the php format from a date string, kinda reversing the string into the php mask.